# Moving a feature to a new XY coordinate

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, coordinates, error, xy

I know how to move a point feature to a new location based on an updated XY coordinate. For example, joining an Excel or dbf table with the new XY cords to the production feature class attribute table based on a common unique identifier. When I export the combined tables (now 1 feature class) I use the following Python code.

```
def XYsetVALUE( shape, X_value, Y_value):
     point = shape.getPart(0)
     point.X = X_value
     point.Y = Y_value
     return point

XYsetVALUE ( !Shape! , !POINT_X! , !POINT_Y! )
```

However, if I try to use this code before exporting the joined tables it does not allow me to move coords. I keep getting an error message. I do need to move features and NOT export the tables together, I need to update the XY coords and move the point features only when the tables are joined.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message.

Comment: Have you tried the code while Start editing ?

Comment: arcpy.Point (!POINT_X! , !POINT_Y!) in a field calculator will do the job. No need to start editing.